# How to loop through a custom post type and return each custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom post type (`artwork`) for pieces of artwork and I have registered a custom taxonomy (`period`) for each period this artwork belongs in. For example, the artwork "The Starry Night" would belong in the "1880 - 1889" Period.

What I need is to be able to loop through the CPT and return each `period` on my home page. This would then link through to the archive of that period. I have tried searching around for this but it's proving hard to find an answer due to the amount of literature out there about just CPT.

I have used [this](http://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/) resource to try to work this out myself but haven't been able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to loop through the posts/CPT if you're just listing the terms with links to the archives?

You can just use the <kbd>[get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/)</kbd> function which will return an array of [`WP_Term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/) objects:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'period',
    'hide_empty' => true,
);

if( $terms = get_terms( $args ) ){
    echo '<ul>';
        foreach( $terms as $term ){
            $url = get_term_link( $term->slug, 'period' );
            echo "<li><a href=\"$url\">{$term->name} ({$term->count})</a></li>";
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}

/**
 * Output:
 *
 * <ul>
 *   <li><a href="/period/80-89">1880-1889 (1)</a><li>
 *   <li><a href="/period/90-99">1890-1899 (3)</a><li>
 * </ul>
 */
```

---

If for some reason you want to loop through your posts, you'll need <kbd>[get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/)</kbd> instead, and put that in your loop, which will get all the terms associated with that post:

> ```html
>     // Loop started above
>
>  if( $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'period' ) ){
>   echo '<ul>';
>    foreach( $terms as $term ){
>     $url = get_term_link( $term->slug, 'period' );
>     echo "<li><a href=\"$url\">{$term->name} ({$term->count})</a></li>";
>    }
>   echo '</ul>';
>  }
>
>     // Finish loop below
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I think I worded my question slightly incorrectly, I didn't need to loop through the posts, just wanted to loop terms. I think where I was going wrong was by getting confused between taxonomies and terms. Thanks again for your help!